# Change equation number latex

Tags: equations, numbering

I would like to quote a part of a paper and would like to keep the same numbering of equations.  For example, suppose in a paper, the equation appears

```
 \begin{equation}
       1 + 1 = 2
 \end{equation}
```

And appears numbered as (5) in the paper, and not (1) which would appear when I type it out in LaTeX.  I would like to give a direct quote of the paper, including the equation number.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could use `\setcounter{equation}{4}` to set the equation number to 5, but this will break your other numbers ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I expect only very very few equations in what I am writing.  I assume I can simply use `setcounter` for each equation.

Comment: You could, but it's not really nice ;-)

Comment: use `amsmath`, use `\tag`, and in the surrounding text, say something like "this is equation (5) from \cite{...}".

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can set the number of the equations yourself with `\tag` and this will keep your equation numbers other than the tagged value the same. This looks odd though and perhaps isn't what you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \tag{5}
   1 + 1 = 2             
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y=mx+c
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this, for instance I can add  some of the surrounding text and put the whole thing as a legit indented quote:  

\begin{quote}
quoted text + 
  equation + 
more quoted text
\end{quote}

Comment: This is very useful, thanks.  I also realized that you can use it to repeat an earlier equation, including its number, by tagging with a ref: `\tag{\ref{othereq}}`.

Comment: This is documented in amsldoc, subsection 3.1.